# myLocationButton button does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I used the function

```
self.view = mapView;
```

button to find the location worked fine, but I did not like the fact that the card was full-screen windows, and I replaced

```
self.view = mapView_; on mapView_.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, 400, 600); [self.view addSubview: mapView_];
```

then disappeared button Mylocation and the inscription Google. how can I get the search button in place and whether the automatic search the user on the map? I mean, once the user has opened the card immediately on the map to determine its location.

```
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"#####"];
   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93
                                                            longitude:30.35
                                                                 zoom:9];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
   mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 600);
    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Much as I have used GMSMApview, It scales to the assigned views Frame, try adding a Subview and then with a specific frame to your main View, and then assign the GMSMapview to the SubVIew added,

Or, If you only want to place a button, then I would simply place it on NAvigation BAr as a  bar button Item, More Easy, more space allotted to the map, for user,